# Usar informação de um event no if else

Tags: if, else, event-listener

Galera,
to fazendo um exercício pra criar um jogo de pedra, papel e tesoura.
Dentro do desenvolvimento cheguei num problema, meu if statement não está funcionando.
To com 1 mês de programação só, então ta meio complexo hahah

```
$(".circle").click((e) => {
  const paper = $("#paper");
  const scissors = $("#scissors");
  const rock = $("#rock");
  const event = e.currentTarget;

  if (event === paper) {
    scissors.addClass("hide");
    rock.addClass("hide");
    $("#triangle").addClass("hide");
  } else if ...*CÓDIGO CONTINUA A MESMA LÓGICA*
```

tenho aqui tambem o console.log da const paper e da const event

```
console paper

S.fn.init [div#paper.circle.paper]
0: div#paper.circle.paper
length: 1
proto: Object(0)
```

```
console event

<div id="paper" role="button" class="circle paper">
   <img src="images/icon-paper.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

No meu pequeno entendimento de programação me encontro sem saber o que fazer!!

Alguém me ajuda ai?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vi você usou o `event` para saber em qual botão clicou. Nesse caso, seria mais fácil usar `this`. `this` consegue, em termos não técnicos, retomar o seletor inicial do código.

Por exemplo: se você tem essa função:

```js
$('#botao').on('click', function() {
  alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

`this` se referirá ao `#botao`, e, portanto, o alerta mostrará o valor do atributo `id` do botão específico.

Fiz um [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/cb37wjq4/) de código de pedra, papel e tesoura para você ver como pode usar ele na prática. É super útil. Além disso, também apresento para você a estrutura condicional `switch`.

Em vez que você incluir um montão de `if` e `else if` para o mesmo valor, você simplesmente pode usar um `switch`. O código fica mais limpo e melhor para ser lido. Olha a diferença abaixo:

```js
var teste = 'Pedro';

if (teste == 'Ana') {
  // código
} else if (teste == 'Bruno') {
  // código
} else if (teste == 'Cláudia') {
  // código
} else if (teste == 'Pedro') {
  // código
} else {
  // o que sobrou
}
```

```js
var teste = 'Pedro';

switch (teste) {
  case ('Ana'): // mesma coisa que (teste == 'Ana')
    // código
    break; // serve para finalizar o switch não ir para os outros cases abaixo.

  case ('Bruno'):
    // código
    break;

  case ('Cláudia'):
    // código
    break;

  case ('Pédro'):
    // código
    break;

  default:
    // o que sobrou
    break;
}
```

Note que no fim do `switch` eu declarei um `default`. Se não houver nenhum `case` igual ao valor, o `default` é usado, como se fosse uma espécie de `else`. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Mano, ainda to olhando o exemplo que vc fez do joguinho, mas acho que vc salvou minha vida aqui.Valeu demais

Comment: @Gabriel, tem `n` jeitos de fazer esse joguinho, assim como qualquer outro código. É a mesma coisa que escrever frases. Você pode criar uma frase com o mesmo sentido que a minha usando outras palavras. Vê o que você gosta no meu código e começa a usar também, mas o importante mesmo é você tentar criar a sua versão, treinar o que aprendeu. Abraços!

Comment: eu tentei aqui e continuou não dando certo usando o this. Eu tinha tentado com ele antes e quando eu faço um console.log dele ele não me retorna um id. Quando faço da forma que você mostrou, meu retorno é undefined.

O meu "botao" é uma div que eu coloquei role="button" pq to usando imagem e outras coisas como botão. Talvez seja isso? 

Mesmo assim, não sei pq nao consigo fazer tem com this e nem com o currentTarget, ja que o retorno dele é o mesmo da minha const papel/terousa/pedra